# SQL query to sum two different values of same ID column in one query

Tags: mysql, sql

kindly, can someone help me with this, I have the following table:

Table Name : balances

```
cname       amount      type
--------------------------------------
Jhon        150     A
Jhon        200     B
Jhon        100     A
Jhon        30      A
Jhon        55      B
```

======================================

I want an SQLquery gives me this result:

```
cname       totalOf_A   totalOf_B  
---------------------------------------  
Jhon        280           255  
=========================================
```

I've tried the follwoing:

```
select ,cname,sum(amount),type from balances group by cname,type
```

the result:

```
cname      amount    type  
----       -----     ----  
Jhon        250       A  
Jhon        255       B
```

so, I want the result in one row and in one query please.
Any suggestions please.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're trying to do is called conditional aggregation. You can use

```
select 
cname,
sum(case when type='A' then amount else 0 end) as total_A,
sum(case when type='B' then amount else 0 end) as total_B 
from balances 
group by cname
```

Comment: thanks a lot my friend, it worked. <3 you made my day.

Comment: because your query will not return the desired output

Comment: @LONG .. what makes you think so?

Comment: @LONG, it worked for me and returned the desired output!

Comment: @vkp, the op's desired output is to show both in one row

Comment: @OsamaGadour check mine to see the difference

Comment: @vkp hmmm, let me double check

Comment: @vkp my mistake, i will upvote again once it is unlocked

Comment: LONG, your query returned only 11 records, and vkp 's returned 19!!! and the total amounts are the same for both queries, am trying now to find out why there are different number of records on the result!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are going to want to use a PIVOT. There are some examples in the docs.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
 select A.cname,A.typeof_A,B.typeof_B
  FROM
  (
  select cname,sum(amount) as typeof_A
   from balances 
   where type = 'A'
   group by cname
   ) as A

   INNER JOIN

   (
  select cname,sum(amount) as typeof_B
   from balances 
   where type = 'B'
   group by cname
   ) as B
  ON B.cname = A.cname
```

Comment: I've tried ur code, but if the sum of type A or B = '0' then the rows doesn't appear in the results!! it really confused me and now i'm interested on finding the answer why this happened !

Comment: ok, i found out why, not all the (cname) has always type A or type B in the records, in some case "cname" only has type A, or only type B, so, in this case when I used ur query and becase of the "inner join"  it only shows me the records that has type A and B